# Wagtail Uploaded Document direct URL

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-search

I am trying to generate a url to an uploaded document (PDF, DOC...etc) on my search results page.  Search is returning the items but there seems to be no url field.  There is a file field which seems to have the file name, but I am unable to get a link back to this file.  I am using the stock document model. Is there some sort of special tag that needs to be used like with the images?? At my wits end.

Search view

```
    if search_query:
    results = []
    page_results = Page.objects.live().search(search_query)
    if page_results:
        results.append({'page': page_results})
    doc_results = Document.objects.all().search(search_query)
    if doc_results:
        results.append({'docs': doc_results})
    img_results = Image.objects.all().search(search_query)
    if img_results:
        results.append({'image': img_results})
    search_results = list(chain(page_results, doc_results, img_results))
    query = Query.get(search_query)

    # Record hit
    query.add_hit()
```

and the template page.

```
        {% for result in search_results %}
        {% for k, v in result.items %}
            {% if k == 'page' %}
                {% for item in v %}
                    <p>
                    <h4><a href="{% pageurl item %}">{{ item }}</a></h4>
                    Type: Article<br>
                    Author: {{ item.specific.owner.get_full_name }}<br>
                    Publish Date: {{ item.specific.last_published_at}} 
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}

            {% elif k == 'docs' %}
                {% for item in v %}
                    <p>
                    <h4><a href="">{{ item.title }}</a></h4>
                    Type: Document<br>
                    Publish Date: {{ item.created_at }}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% elif k == 'image' %}
                {% for item in v %}
                    <p>
                        {% image item original as item_img %}
                    <h4><a href="{{ item_img.url }}" target="_blank">{{ item.title }}</a></h4>
                    Type: Image<br>
                    Publish Date: {{ item.created_at }}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif%}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you already tried using `{{ item.url }}`? It should work...

Comment: There is no url available.  That is my problem.  Unless there is some special tags I need to use like I did on the image.  But I have not been able to find it at all. I output the meta fields for Document in my view to test and no URL.  I can get the file name and i theory I could create a URL. But I don't know how to route that.

Comment: Try running `./manage.py shell` `from wagtail.documents.models import Document` and `Document.objects.first().url` it should return url...

Comment: `{{ item.url }}` should definitely work - it's [defined in the Wagtail code here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/4cfd303db9c29ae582d35820c6e6e4edfd23ec6f/wagtail/documents/models.py#L147). When you say you output the meta fields for Document in your view, do you mean you used `item._meta.get_fields()`? You won't find it there, because it's a method / property, not a field.

Comment: Running the manage.py shell. The output produces URL such as /documents/4/xxx.pdf  This appears to be same location as in admin console when hovering over the file name.  Number seems to change depending on file. Regarding the {{ item.url }} I get invalid block tag. Something is a miss.  Might try recreating the instance from scratch. I have gone astray somewhere.